# Динамически созданные объекты (factory Method)

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc, php

Добрый день.

Скажите, есть ли возможность при помощи PhpDoc комментировать методы, которые возвращают динамически сгенерированные объекты. Нужно это для вызова подсказок в IDE PhpStrom.

Конструкция вида `@return first|second` не очень удобна, так как количество генерируемых объектов не ограничено.

Примитивный пример:

```
class first {

    function getMain() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}

class second {
    function getSecond() {
        return "SeconD";
    }
}

/**
 * @param $name
 *
 */
function getClass( $name ) {
    return new $name;
}
$class = getClass( 'first' );
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы заработали подсказки в `phpStorm`, надо использовать файл `.phpstorm.meta.php`:

```
<?php
namespace PHPSTORM_META { // we want to avoid the pollution

    /** @noinspection PhpUnusedLocalVariableInspection */
    /** @noinspection PhpIllegalArrayKeyTypeInspection */
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = [
        \ORM::factory('') => [
            'File' instanceof \Model_File,
            'Gallery' instanceof \Model_Gallery,
            'User' instanceof \Model_User,
            // ...
        ],
    ];
}
```

Этот пример указывает, с объектом какого класса будет происходить работа после вызовов, вроде:

```
ORM::factory('User')->...
```

Файл надо добавить в корень проекта и перезапустить IDE.  
Как заточить конкретно под ваш пример с функцией, я не скажу, но можете посмотреть документацию по этому файлу где-то тут: [PhpStorm Advanced Metadata](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata).

Comment: Большое спасибо! 
Ух как это круто :)

С функцией это выглядит так 
$STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = [
  \myFunction('') => [ ........

Comment: А вам спасибо за дополнение.

Answer (score 0):

Но почему бы просто не использовать комментарий `@var`?

```
/** $var $class first */
$class = getClass( 'first' );
```

Дополнение после него прекрасно работает.

Comment: При каждом вызове getClass( 'first' ); писать /** $var $class first */ утомительно, к тому же @xEdelweiss предложил отлично решение.